# Modifying text in docx through Python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

I am currently trying to open an existing Word document, modify a line by inserting a raw input at the end, then save it as an overwrite to the original "DOCX". I am using the "DOCX" module. I'm able to create a new document, write in it, then save it... however cannot figure out how to modify an existing line in an existing "DOCX".

`doc = docx.Document()
 paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()`

so far, i've tried this out.. the problem is the paragraph i need to modify is paragraph 0, and this code places my text at the bottom of the page on a new paragraph.

```
import docx
paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
doc = docx.Document("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.docx")
doc.add_paragraph("hello")
docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x03697170
doc.save("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.docx")
```

How can I go about instructing python to write at the end of an existing string in a paragraph then save it overwriting the original?

Comment: That's not really a *question* though, is it? Please read [ask].

Comment: made an edit, thanks for the headsup! @jonrsharpe

Comment: There seems to be plenty documentation available. Did you read past [the very first page](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (from which, it seems, your current code came from)?

Comment: @RadLexus yes i did. sorry i wasn't more specific. posted an update of my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.docx")
doc.paragraphs[0].add_run("hello")
doc.save("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for something like this?

```
from docx import Document
existing_docx = Document(r'path_to_existing.docx')
for paragraph in existing_docx.paragraphs:
    paragraph.text = paragraph.text + your_text
existing_docx.save(r'same_path_or_another.docx')
```

The new docx will contain your text after every paragraph with the code above.

Comment: hi thanks for your response. this looks like it will modify every paragraph in the document, when i only want to modify the ending of the 0 paragraph. i've edited my question with my last tried code. thank you!

Comment: @dan - Try: `existing_docx.paragraphs[0].text += your_text`. Better: `existing_docx.paragraphs[0].add_run(your_text)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ 's comment is correct. This will change the first (index 0) paragraph only.

Answer (score 0):

To get paragraph 0 try:

`para = doc.paragraphs[0]`